# Writing C# code inside my razor view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code inside my Razor view:-

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('body').on("click", "#transferall", function () {
var buttonname = $("#assetTypeName").val();
var dialogtitle = buttonname.ToString().Substring(buttonname.ToString().IndexOf("add") + 1);
```

but currently the script will raise the following error:-

```
TypeError: buttonname.ToString is not a function
https://localhost:44300/Rack/Details/702
Line 541
```

so can anyone advice if it is possible to write such a code inside my Razor view script section?

Regards

Comment: you cannot access a javascript variable in server-side code.   Alexander (below) makes a good suggestion

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use javascript there :-)

```
buttonname.substring(buttonname.indexOf("add") + 1)
```

instead of

```
buttonname.ToString().Substring(buttonname.ToString().IndexOf("add") + 1);
```

Comment: Yes, in a script tag the C# code wouldn't run because the script is run client side (javascript) not server side (C#).

Comment: Not entirely true, @DLeh. You can have Razor code inside the script tag, but it will only run on the server to deliver **static text** to the browser. The problem is that the OP is trying to run the C# code on the browser after it gets to the client.

Comment: well yes. I suppose I meant "c# code couldn't run on javascript objects".